# OpenGL point sprites with depth testing - a blending issue?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, blending, depth-buffer, point-sprites

I am rendering point sprites (using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS) as a user's drawing strokes. I am storing these points in vertex buffer objects such that I need to perform depth testing in order for the sprites to appear in the correct order when they're submitted for drawing.

I'm seeing an odd effect when rendering these drawing strokes, as shown by the following screenshot:

[image: Point Sprite Blending Issue]

Note the background-coloured 'border' around the edge of the blue stroke, where it is drawn over the green. The user drew the blue stroke after the green stroke, but when the VBOs are redrawn the blue stroke gets drawn first. When it comes to draw the green stroke, depth testing kicks in and sees that it should be behind the blue stroke, and so does this, with *some* success. It appears to me to be some kind of blending issue, or to do with incorrectly calculating the colour in the fragment shader? The edges of all strokes should be transparent, however it appears that the fragment shader combines it with the background texture when processing those fragments.

In my app I have created a depth renderbuffer and called `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` using `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)`. I have experimented with `glDepthMask()` to no avail. Blending is set to `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, and the point sprite colour uses premultiplied alpha values. The drawing routine is very simple:

- Bind render-to-texture FBO.
- Draw background texture.
- Draw point sprites (from a number of VBOs).
- Draw this FBO's texture to the main framebuffer.
- Present the main framebuffer.

**EDIT**

Here is some code from the drawing routine.

Setup state prior to drawing:

```
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

Drawing routine:

```
[drawingView setFramebuffer:drawingView.scratchFramebuffer andClear:YES];
glUseProgram(programs[PROGRAM_TEXTURE]);
[self drawTexture:[self textureForBackgroundType:self.backgroundType]];

glUseProgram(programs[PROGRAM_POINT_SPRITE]);

// ...
// Draw all VBOs containing point sprite data
// ...

[drawingView setFramebuffer:drawingView.defaultFramebuffer andClear:YES];
glUseProgram(programs[PROGRAM_TEXTURE]);
[self drawTexture:drawingView.scratchTexture];

[drawingView presentFramebuffer:drawingView.defaultFramebuffer];
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to draw non opaque geometries you have to z-sort them from back to front. This has been the only way to get a proper blending for many years. These days there are some algorithms for order independent transparency like Dual Depth Peeling but they are not applicable to iOS.

Comment: Gah, that's the answer I was hoping not to see! Thanks for your response though. Z-sorting my sprites could prove a little tricky, since strokes use different textures (as seen in the screenshot). I'd like to keep the number of VBOs to a minimum, but I'll see what I can manage given that they need to remain in the correct order.

Comment: I imagine the different strokes are in different VBOs. All you have to do here is sort the VBOs not the point sprites... Unless you want to draw with the green again and combine the 1st stroke with the 3rd one since they are going to use the same texture. This seems like a large amount of particles. I'm not sure the best thing to do is to draw them every frame. If you making a drawing type of app you should consider drawing the old layers in render target and just draw the current one on top. Then if you have undo type of operation you'll have to redraw them from the first layer.

Comment: Yes they are stored in VBOs, and the problem is like you describe - if I store all strokes of one particular texture in one VBO, then draw different textures in between, when I come to draw all the VBOs they will be out of order. I have fixed this part though, and create a new VBO each time the user changes stroke texture, otherwise I cram as many points in as possible. I am not drawing the VBOs every frame - I use the render-to-texture approach for drawing, and this easily achieves 60fps. I need the VBOs to support eraser & undo/redo actions.

Comment: It is a disappointing answer, but aren't the strokes in this case naturally ordered back-to-front by the painting process, reducing the need for sorting them?